# Two buttons side by side

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make two hyperlinked buttons go side by side.  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481606/making-two-html-buttons-go-side-by-side) but can not make the answers work.  Below are my two attempts to make the buttons go side by side.  The first attempt works but hyperlinks to the wrong location.  The second one hyperlinks correctly but is not side by side.  The third based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706189/2-html-buttons-that-i-want-to-be-side-by-side-on-the-same-line) doesn't link anywhere but I think that has to do with using links instead of `Javascript:submitRequests()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            button {
               float: left;
            }

            button:first-child {
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/paste2.html" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="paste2">
    </form>
    <form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/colSplit.html" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="colSplit">
    </form>

    Attempt 1
    <form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/paste2.html" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="paste2">
            <form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/colSplit.html" target="_blank">
                <input type="submit" value="colSplit">
            </form>
    </form>

    Attempt 2   
    <form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/paste2.html" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="paste2">
    </form><form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/colSplit.html" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="colSplit">
    </form>

    Attempt 3
    <div class="container">
        <button onclick="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/paste2.html">paste2</button>
        <button onclick="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/colSplit.html">colSplit</button> text
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A js fiddle would be nice

Comment: Do you need to POST form values, or just link to the pages?

Comment: I need to link to pages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just need plain links to work, just *use links* and style them to look like buttons (see also [Styling an anchor tag to look like a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187008/styling-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-submit-button)):

```
<style>
    .button {
        appearance: button;
        -moz-appearance: button;
        -webkit-appearance: button;
        text-decoration: none; 
        font: menu; 
        color: ButtonText;
        display: inline-block; 
        padding: 2px 8px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <a href="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/paste2.html" class="button">paste2</a>
    <a href="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/colSplit.html" class="button">colSplit</a> text
</div>
```

You *could* also do `<a href="..."><button>paste2</button></a>` but this is [not actually legal HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5). FWIW, Firefox does seem to render it correctly though.

Comment: This is precisely what I was after.

Comment: Could you expand on the style the links to look like buttons?

Answer (score 2):

`button`s would line up side by side automatically since they're `display: inline-block` by default (I think). I'd remove the `float: left` since it could be causing some issues when nesting.

You should never nest forms. It'll lead to some really screwy things.

However, if you want two forms side by side you can make them do that by adding `display: inline` to them. Here's a small demo: http://jsbin.com/UgaMiYu/1/edit

The `onclick` attribute should't make any difference at all.

Comment: Thanks Bill I'm a newb.  I was more after the look of the button with hyperlink functionality.

Comment: Got it! Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to add css to attempt 2. how about this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/paste2.html" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="paste2"/></form>
<form action="http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/colSplit.html" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="colSplit"/>
    </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
form{
    float:left;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uzDZN/

**NOTE:** Add class to form which has this buttons. Otherwise css may effect other form elements in website.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing regular buttons and setting their display property to either inline or inline-block worked for me.